# How to parse json response from Bigquery results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-bigquery, bigdata

I tried sample javascript code to call Google bigQuery API ( https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#client-side-javascript )

**Js:**

```
function runQuery() {
   var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
      'projectId': project_id,
      'timeoutMs': '30000',
      'query': 'SELECT TOP(repository_language, 5) as language, COUNT(*) as count FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] WHERE repository_language != "";'
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {     
        console.log(response);
        var results = response.result.rows ;
        $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(results, null));
    });
}
```

Above big query **returns** :

```
[{"f":[{"v":"JavaScript"},{"v":"949899"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Ruby"},{"v":"640659"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Java"},{"v":"568202"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Python"},{"v":"484852"}]},{"f":[{"v":"PHP"},{"v":"453830"}]}]
```

Please help me how to parse the values from above results in JSON Format ?

```
{"JavaScript": "949899", "Ruby": "640659", "Java": "568202", "Python": "484852", "PHP": "453830" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eval is a security risk.

```
var text = '[{"f":[{"v":"JavaScript"},{"v":"949899"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Ruby"},{"v":"640659"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Java"},{"v":"568202"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Python"},{"v":"484852"}]},{"f":[{"v":"PHP"},{"v":"453830"}]}]';
myData = JSON.parse(text);
alert(myData[4].f[0].v);​
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jv7vm/

```
var a='[{"f":[{"v":"JavaScript"},{"v":"949899"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Ruby"},{"v":"640659"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Java"},{"v":"568202"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Python"},{"v":"484852"}]},{"f":[{"v":"PHP"},{"v":"453830"}]}]';

var evala=eval('('+a+')');

for(i=0;i<evala.length;i++)
{
document.write(evala[i].f[0].v+' '+evala[i].f[1].v+'<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from below javascript

```
var total = response.result.totalRows;
var data = [];
for(i=0; i < total; i++){
            data[i]= [ response.rows[i].f[0]["v"], response.rows[i].f[1]["v"] ];
        }

 console.log(data);
```